# Click button of java build website using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I;m in the process of learning the web scraping using VBA and I've come across the website listed within my code which is Java build.

My goal is to click **Next** button from the VBA code, but I can not identify it when looking at "behind the scene" code. When using "Inspect" element i see the button reference but when I list all the links in my excel it is not there. 
Then I looked at the page using CTR-U (in Chrome) and the page looks completely different and has a lot of Java Code. I am not familiar with Java therefore could you please describe how is the mechanism of decoding such a Java page?

Here is my code:

```
Sub first_template()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument


ie.Top = 0
ie.Left = 0
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "http://www.amaaonline.com/member-directory/"

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set input_elements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

i = 4
For Each element In input_elements
Cells(i, 1).Value = element.innerHTML
i = i + 1
Next element
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: We need to see the html code for your website, specifically the select boxes or text boxes you are trying to change

Comment: hello , this is the website -  (http://www.amaaonline.com/member-directory/) and I try to click the **next** button from vba.10x

Comment: any expert here willing to help ?

Comment: That website will not load on my system.  I waited 3 minutes and it still would not finish loading.  Sorry, without knowing what you are up against no one will be able to help.

Comment: In chrome it loads...I can put the code of the page here but it would be really long and i don't believe helpful. If you have an email I can send you some print screens of the website and the code. I'd really appreciate your help